# What is the use for ssh keys with no passphrase?

Tags: ssh, public-key-encryption, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

What is the point of allowing `ssh-keygen` to generate empty passphrase keys when it is not recommended to use such keys for remote login? What situations would such keys be useful for?

Comment: Do you have a quote for this not being recommended?

Comment: @Thilo No, I don't. Upon thinking after your comment I realized what I meant by 'recommended' was something more like a 'tacit recommendation' as every documentation of the subject matter I've seen suggests entering a strong passphrase.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [security.se]. It's off-topic here.

Comment: I agree it would have been better off in the other forums. How do I move a question?

Comment: You could flag it for migration, but it is easier just to ask there and delete the question *if it has not yet been answered*. Try and use migration only for answered questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The passphrase protects the key in its storage on your local computer.

Even without a passphrase, a key is still better than a password, as it can only be "stolen" if someone has physical access to your computer (or at least some kind of network access to the files on your computer), whereas a password can be brute-forced (or leaked from any number of places in case you re-use passwords).